# Creating a sub domain with php

Tags: php, html, subdomain, cpanel

I have hosting with a cpanel accelerated 2 panel here I can manually create a sub domain but is there a way to create a sub domain with a php script so they input the sub domain they like then click submit and it will create a sub domain for them. Thank you.

If there is a php script to create a sub domain what is it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CPanel's API for this. Have a look here:

[http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/XmlApi#DNS functions](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/XmlApi#DNS%20functions)

More specifically, here:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/AddZoneRecord

Comment: I am sorry I am quiet a noob. I understand the logic behind it but I simply do not quiet under stand it in depth. And this api doesn't seem to have the abilty to add a sub domain and if it did how would I do this. Thank you

Comment: You can add the subdomain via an A record using the API. Most of the things you need are in the links I posted, presuming you know how to code. Nobody is just going to give you the code to do it, since that's what developers are for.

Comment: Yeah I'm i've gone and payed some one to do it :)
I guess it was probably for the best